# Increasing the constant rows for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets where the first dataset value is changing according to the number of objects I detected. My second dataset is a constant value where these columns should be joined with the first dataset. Now the problem is that if I have 50 rows in the first dataset and 20 rows in the second dataset. How are the remaining rows of the second dataset filled as they have a constant value?

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df1.head()
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv)
df2.head()
```

[image]

Now I joined these two tables:

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, rsuffix='_right')
df_join.head()
```

[image]

how to these constant value increase based on the number of rows in `df1`? Now they are `NaN`. For example, the column `BitSizeValue` is `8.0`, this show fill all the row of the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill `constant` values? You mean you need to fill that Extra `Nan` with constant values that are `above`?

If so

```
df_join=df_join.fillna(method='ffill')
df_join.head()
```

Comment: No, this NaN values are from the missing row. I want it to have the same value as it has in the above rows. for example, the column `BitSizeValue` is `8.0`, this value should be come instead of NaN.

Comment: Yeah above code works for this case..Can u try?

Comment: has it Worked?.